# How to create custom block in wagtail?

Tags: django, image, wagtail

This is my `StreamField`:

```
body = StreamField([
    ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
    ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
])
```

And my question is: how to add my own Block that I can pass to `StreamField`? I meant block that contains multiple images, something like block? I didn't find answer for my question in wagtail docs.

Comment: This is covered by http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#structural-block-types

Answer (score 6):

When you asked:

> I meant block that contains multiple images, something like block?

Here is an example of something you could try, I am not sure what specifically you are trying to achieve so I left it fairly generic but modify it how you like.

```py
class GalleryBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """
    Nameable gallery with multiple images.
    """
    name = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
    images = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock([
            ("image", ImageChooserBlock(required=True)),
            ("alt_text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, max_length=100)),
        ])
    )
```

Then you would, of course, need to add this into your StreamField for `body`.

Something like this maybe.

```py
body = StreamField([
    ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
    ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ('gallery', GalleryBlock(icon='image')), # add this line
])
```

Hope this helps you see how flexible and awesome these built-in blocks are and how awesome StreamField can be. Sometimes you need to combine them to build a specific structure for your needs.